# Is it possible to set the expiration date of a certificate?

Tags: ad-certificate-services

I am trying to test certificate validation logic in an installer.

I have a test domain with Active Directory Certificate Services installed.  Both the domain controller and CertServ are base installations with minimal configuration.

Is there a way to control the expiration date of a certificate when requesting a certificate?

Ideally I would like issue a certificates that expire today, tomorrow and yesterday(already expired)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ADCS You can change the validity period in the certificate templates. I suggest you duplicate a template and then go to the properties / general tab and you will see an option for validity period.

This only affects certificates that are issued after the change. Validity periods of previously issued certs will not change